# Finding out cyclic reference to be gc collected in python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

As I understand, python keeps reference counts for each object and collect them when the count drops to 0. It can also detect cyclic references and collect them by running gc.collect.

I would like to utilize the first mechanism as mush as possible since gc.collect is not very performant. So I would like to turn off auto gc collect and know what objects will be collected if I run gc.collect. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Look at [the documentation for gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html).  It has lots of methods that can help with this.